# How to add and use external assemblies in solutions?

Tags: deployment, solution-package, solution-deployment, assembly-references, packaging

I need to use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` in my code. In the solution package, I included this external dll in the Additional Assemblies. It looks like this:

[image]

I also need to reference it, so that I can use its classes in the code. So I added a reference to the same file. But now, when I want to deploy my solution it shoots error with the message:

> "SharePointProject" and "SharePointProject" contain a file that deploys to the same Package location: DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

I guess the problem is that I haven't referenced the dll from additional package assemblies list, but directly from the file, though I could be wrong here.

How do I make sure that the external assembly `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` gets deployed with the solution and I can use its classes in my code? Thanks!

Comment: I removed the reference from project (not package) and commented the code which uses its classes, just to test the deployment without it. I still get the same error, which means that the edit in the additional assemblies for package are causing it. Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Have you copied or changed the location of any item in your solution?

Comment: No, I am aware of that issue. If I remove the additional assembly from package, the solution deploys just fine. This leads me to a conclusion that the issue is related to adding external assemblies to the package.

Comment: Ensure 'Copy Local' is set to false in your assembly's reference.

Comment: Did you set the flag "specific Version" to false. This error comes up if you want to deploy two different versions of one assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue recently.
To solve this, I just removed the entries in 'Safe Controls' and 'Class Resources' section and saved 'Edit Existing Assembly' form. Then, it got deployed without issue.

Comment: +1, I also had a solution I needed to include OpenXML.dll with.  I installed the SDK on my dev machine.  In my project, I referenced the dll that had been installed in the GAC (by the SDK), but in my package, I added an existing assembly (with a source path of `..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`, the path of the dll in the SDK package but outside the GAC), and I did *not* put anything in the 'Safe Controls' or 'Class Resources' sections.  Packages and deploys fine like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to incorrect locations of SharePoint Project Items (SPI). After you add your assembly click on `Show All Files` in the `Solution Explorer` in Visual Studio and locate the `SharePointProjectItem.spdata` file. Open it and make sure that the `Target` attribute of all the `ProjectItemFileSource` elements points to the correct location.